# How to solve for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, factoring

$W(4d^2 (1-x^2)^2) = abc^3x \sqrt{(\pi^2 (i-x^2)^2 + 16 x^2) }$

I have to find x ,i have the values of all other constants ,
I tried to separate it using partial fraction but I am stuck.
a=3
b=4
c=7
d=9
w=19

Comment: I'm just curious: what's the value of $\mathrm{pie}$?

Comment: @user1067252, I edited you question. Is that how the equation should look like?

Comment: Assuming that W is not a special function, you may want to consider the value of $x$ that makes $(\pi^2 (i-x^2)^2 + 16 x^2) >= 0$. This may give you a start.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the terms you have x^4 on the left, which will go to x^8 when you square both sides to get rid of the square root.  But you will have all terms in x having an even exponent, so you can define y=x^2 to get a quartic.  These have a [messy solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function).  Without knowing the constants I don't think we can help further.  You might look for rational roots using the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)